# Outlook 2010 - rule running a VBA script gives "Script "" doesn't exist or is invalid" error

Tags: vba, outlook, rules, outlook-2010

Windows 7, Outlook 2010 Exchange account. Intermediate Excel VBA programmer, newbie Outlook VBA coder.

I need to ensure that all incoming emails are bcc'd to a gmail account. I modified an online macro to suit. It works flawlessly on all incoming emails, EXCEPT for those downloaded at first boot and Outlook startup. It resided in ThisOutlookSession.

```
 Private Sub Application_NewMailEx(ByVal EntryIDCollection As String)
     Dim varEntryIDs
     Dim objItem
     Dim myItem As MailItem
     Dim i As Integer
     varEntryIDs = Split(EntryIDCollection, ",")
     For i = 0 To UBound(varEntryIDs)
         Set objItem = Application.Session.GetItemFromID(varEntryIDs(i))

         If TypeOf objItem Is MailItem Then                     

             Set myItem = objItem.Forward
             myItem.Recipients.Add "bcc.hwb@gmail.com"

             myItem.DeleteAfterSubmit = True                    
             myItem.Send
             Set myItem = Nothing
         Else
             Debug.Print "Skipping " & TypeName(objItem)
             Set myItem = Nothing
         End If
     Next
 End Sub
```

A question to the forum kindly educated me that the queued messages upon Outlook startup and folder update do not fire the NewMail and NewMailEx event routines. They recommended setting up a rule that runs a script for all incoming mail.

I attempted to call the routine and the script was not "visible." I searched a while and found that only scripts operating as MailItems are recognized, and they had to be in a module. I modified the script to pass this test and it was now visible.

```
 Sub IncomingBCC(myItem As MailItem)

     Dim EntryIDCollection As String
     Dim varEntryIDs
     Dim objItem
   ' Dim myItem As MailItem
     Dim i As Integer
     varEntryIDs = Split(EntryIDCollection, ",")
     For i = 0 To UBound(varEntryIDs)
         Set objItem = Application.Session.GetItemFromID(varEntryIDs(i))

         If TypeOf objItem Is MailItem Then                     

             Set myItem = objItem.Forward
             myItem.Recipients.Add "bcc.hwb@gmail.com"

             myItem.DeleteAfterSubmit = True                    
             myItem.Send
             Set myItem = Nothing
         Else
             Debug.Print "Skipping " & TypeName(objItem)
             Set myItem = Nothing
         End If
     Next

 End Sub
```

Now, Outlook rules "see" the script, and allow the rule to be created. When run, it generates an error as follows:
"The script "" doesn't exist or is invalid." 
I could find no pertinent online help on this error even after extensive searching.

I would appreciate some guidance as how to proceed.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to get the item by using the EntryID values:

```
 varEntryIDs = Split(EntryIDCollection, ",")
 For i = 0 To UBound(varEntryIDs)
     Set objItem = Application.Session.GetItemFromID(varEntryIDs(i))
```

You need to use the item passed as a parameter. The EntryID values are not passed any longer to the VBA sub.

Comment: Could you please show the correct code? I simply cannot get this routine to cooperate. I would be in your debt.